# Display popup message when i hover on taxonomy link to display description

Tags: taxonomy-terms, navigation

I used **Hierarchical Select** module in my academic web site for student to select course from dropdown menu and it is works good but i have problem, for each course i  want to add course description as a popup message when we click on course link(Course link displayed as taxonomy link). Can you help me to solve this problem.
I really appreciate to you.[image]

Answer (score 0):

It can be easily done with [Simple Dialog](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_dialog) module. All instructions you can find at the module page

Answer (score 0):

For what it sounds like, personally, I'd go with the [qtip](https://www.drupal.org/project/qtip) project. I know it's pretty powerful (as far as getting the behavior with hover/click or getting the look how you want it), but I can't speak to if it's good for doing more advanced things; as you said you only want a "description" though, it's what I'd recommend.

Comment: Thank you for help,  My problem is that the link which is displaying my webpage are specially Taxonomy and for that i cna't use qtip module. I found taxonomy tooltip module to accomplish this task but i can't download jquery tooltip plugin from that site. So, i am stuck here.